# When two points of a triangle are known, how can we find the third point on a circle?

Tags: geometry, coordinate

Suppose there is a triangle ABC on a circle, where A is the center of the circle and B and C are two points the the boundary of the same circle, we know the following things about this triangle:

1. 2-d Coordinate value of A (x1,y1) i.e. (357,257)
2. 2-d Coordinate value of B (x2,y2) i.e. (93,169)
3. Distance from A to B is 278 (radius of the circle)
4. Distance from A to C is 278 (radius of the circle)
5. Distance from B to C is 244
6. angle ∠BAC ≡ ∠CAB ≡ ∠A = 52°

Now the question is:

How to find the 2-d coordinate value of Point C (x3,y3) ???

Answer (score 1):

You can just rotate B point relative to A point by 52° (don't forget to use radians). Change angle sign if you need rotate in another direction.

```
x3=x1+(x2-x1)*Cos(52)-(y2-y1)*Sin(52)
y3=y1+(x2-x1)*Sin(52)+(y2-y1)*Cos(52)
```

Answer (score 0):

So another way of looking at it might be that the circle is centred on (357, 357), you have one point on the outside of the circle and you want to advance by so many degrees around the circle? It seems to be that (5) <=> (6) (or, I guess, the constraints are inconsistent).

Naturally there will be two solutions since your constraints allow two answers, which would look like neighbouring slices of the circle if both drawn together.

The simplest solution would probably be to use arctan to get the angle from the horizontal of the line segment from A to B, then add or subtract 52 to that and use sin/cos to get a new point on the outside of the circle.

E.g. (in C, assuming I've remembered my quadrants correctly)

```
float angleOfAB = atan2f(B.y - A.y, B.x - A.x);
float angleOfAC = angleOfAB + 52.0f * M_PI / 180.0f; // in radians

// could use squartf here if the radius is unknown

Position C;
C.x = A.x + 278.0f * cos(angleOfAC);
C.y = A.y + 278.0f * sin(angleOfAC);
```